# How to plot a graph for each date in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I have dateset `df` looks like below:

```
    id         timestamp        data     group_id
99  265 2019-11-28 15:44:34.027  22.5         1
100 266 2019-11-28 15:44:34.027  23.5         2
101 267 2019-11-28 15:44:34.027  27.5         3
102 273 2019-11-28 15:44:38.653  22.5         1
104 275 2019-11-28 15:44:38.653  22.5         2
```

I want to plot a graph for data on the same date. I thus created a new column `Date` based on `timestamp`. The code is as below:

```
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

df = df[df['temperature']>0]
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-01 00:00:00')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-02-05 00:00:00')
df = df.loc[(df['timestamp'] > start_date) & (df['timestamp'] < end_date)]

df['Date'] = [datetime.datetime.date(d) for d in df['timestamp']] 
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


GROUP_ID = 2
df = df[df['group_id'] == GROUP_ID]

for date in df['Date'].unique():  
  df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
  df = df[df['Date'] == date]   # Edited Question: added this line and received error `TypeError: no numeric data to plot`.
  df.plot(x='timestamp', y='data', figsize=(30, 16)) 
  plt.axhline(y=40, color='r', linestyle='-')
  plt.axhline(y=25, color='b', linestyle='-')

  df['top_lim'] = 40
  df['bottom_lim'] = 25

  plt.fill_between(df['timestamp'], df['bottom_lim'], df['data'],
                where=(df['data'] >= df['bottom_lim'])&(df['data'] <= df['top_lim']),
                facecolor='orange', alpha=0.3)

  mask = (df['data'] <= df['top_lim'])&(df['data'] >= df['bottom_lim'])
  plt.scatter(df['timestamp'][mask], df['data'][mask], marker='.', color='black')

  cumulated_time = df['timestamp'][mask].diff().sum()

  plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left = 0.3)
  plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
  plt.ylabel('data')
  plt.show()
```

As a result, I received 3 graphs, looking exactly the same, and plotting all data of the **entire time interval** between `2020-02-01` and `2020-02-05`, rather than having **daily data** plotted on each graph.

What is wrong with my code?

---

Edited Question:

Added line `df = df[df['Date'] == date]` and received error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-58d9f4ed160f> in <module>()

     34   df = df[df['Date'] == date]
---> 35   df.plot(x='timestamp', y='data', figsize=(30, 16))
     36   plt.axhline(y=40, color='r', linestyle='-')
     37   plt.axhline(y=25, color='b', linestyle='-')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
    412         # no non-numeric frames or series allowed
    413         if is_empty:
--> 414             raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
    415 
    416         # GH25587: cast ExtensionArray of pandas (IntegerArray, etc.) to

TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

I think this is because that there is no data on `2020-02-02`. So the new question: How can I skip the iteration where there is no data for the particular date?

Comment: You aren't filtering the data by `date` inside the for loop. It's totally ok if you are getting the same plot 3 times. You should filter your data inside the for loop and create a new dataframe for each date and then plot that dataframe. You could try something like `df_date = df.loc[df['Date']==Date]`. Then plot using `df_date`.

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa Hi I have tried that but received an error. Please see edited question. Thank you!

Comment: That's why you have to create a new DataFrame. If you use the same name `df`, then you lose the data for other dates. Look at the example I provided `df_date = df.loc[df['Date']==Date]`

Inside the loop, you have to replace `df` by `df_date`

Comment: @JuanJavierSantosOchoa It's working now. Thank you very much. If you had posted an answer I could have accepted it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't filtering the data by date inside the for loop. It's totally ok if you are getting the same plot 3 times. You should filter your data inside the for loop and create a new dataframe for each date and then plot that dataframe. You could try something like df_date = df.loc[df['Date']==Date]. Then plot using df_date.

Comment: Btw I would like to add a title to indicate the total amount of cumulative time in between the boundaries on a certain date, using `plt.title(f'Cumulative time in range for ' , date ,':=' , cumulated_time})` but it didn't work. It worked with `plt.title(f'Cumulative time in range = {cumulated_time}')` though. Do you know why?

Comment: `plt.title(f'Cumulative time in range for ' , date ,':=' , cumulated_time})` This syntax is incorrect because you are separating your text with comma. If you had concatenated with `+` it would work: `plt.title('Cumulative time in range for ' + str(date)  + ':=' +  str(cumulated_time))`. Highly recommend you read this: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. This is what I have been looking for. Do you know of any resources I can use to build a structured understanding in Python?

Comment: Btw, the date in the title is `2020-02-05 T00:00:000000000`. Do you know how I can keep the date only? Thanks a lot

Comment: I recommend this book: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/. Also this course is a good starting point https://www.coursera.org/learn/python 

The easiest way to do it is maybe str(date)[0:10]